# Why can an Array not be used in useState where the generic is of the same type as the array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have defined a data type

```
interface IOptions {
  name: string
  value: any
  type: string
}
```

And created an array of that type

```
let myTableData: IOptions[] = [
    {name: "A string", value: "string to display", type: "string"},
    {name: "A number", value: 42, type: "number"},
    {name: "A combobox Enum style", value: "1", type: "enum"},
    {name: "A bool flag", value: true, type: "bool"},
];
```

NowI want to define a state which uses this data type and is typed

```
let [state, setState] = React.useState<IOptions[]>({
  myTableData
});
```

However this gives me the error message

> Argument of type '{ myTableData: IOptions[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IOptions[] | (() => IOptions[])'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myTableData' does not exist in type 'IOptions[] | (() => IOptions[])'.ts(2345)

Why is that? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useState<{myTableData: IOptions[]}>({myTableData});
```

You're telling typescript the state is an array of IOptions and then giving it an object, let me know if this helps

Comment: It works, but I don't seem to understand why. Can you add an example where the state would have another variable, say a string? would it be something like `useState<{myTableData: IOptions[], myString: string}>({myTableData, "a string"});` ?

Comment: `useState<{myTableData: IOptions[], otherKey: string}>({myTableData, otherKey: "hello"});`

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the type to be an array of IOptions, whereas you are setting the state to be an object with key as `myTableData`

You can either choose to just have array in the state like

```
let [state, setState] = React.useState<IOptions[]>(myTableData);
```

or change the type to be an object

```
interface DataObj = {
    myTableData: IOptions[]
}
let [state, setState] = React.useState<DataObj>({
    myTableData
});
```